# WebRTC doesn't work with the WIFI connection but work with mobile data

Tags: connection, webrtc

WebRTC doesn't work with WIFI connection but works with mobile data.
When launched with a mobile date, an offer and candidates are sent, then when connected, a response and candidates are sent, and everything is connected. But when I give it through wifi, everything goes the same, but the videos do not connect.ICE connection state change: disconnected. What could be the problem?

At the same time, the problem occurs with 2 independent providers in Ukraine. For example, in the USA everything works correctly. Firewall off

Answer (score 1):

ICE failed means there were no candidate pairs discovered via which peers could reach each other.

It could be caused by many different reasons.

Top-1 in my opinion is that you're behind NAT and you're not using [turn server](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/03-connecting/#turn) that is accessible via ipv4 from public network.

Even if you're not behind NAT it still might be an issue as browsers might restrict ICE candidates discovery. Especially if user hasn't granted access to his mic / camera (it [does affects](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-ip-handling-01) candidates gathering).

You might deploy your own turn server (see [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn)), or use a cloud one, for example [Xirsys](https://xirsys.com/). They also have a free trial.

The other reason might be that the provider is blocking UDP / WebRTC traffic. You can prove it using tcpdump on both sides of connection.

For further reading, [here's a great article](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/webrtc-issues-and-how-to-debug-them) on how to approach debugging webrtc.

Comment: I think the problem is elsewhere. I tried to connect with another wifi and another router model and everything went well.

Comment: When it's direct without Wi-Fi, it doesn't work either.
Different providers with the same router (TP-Link) do not work, but 1 provider with Xiaomi router worked

Comment: I contacted the provider and they gave me an external IP and unblocked ports 25, 139, 445. Everything started working for me. The question remains - can I, as a developer, bypass this problem for other users?

Comment: I can't see, how unlocking these ports could have helped, it might be something else that changed... I would still recommend you starting with a turn server. Without it there's absolutely no guarantee, that users are able to connect.